# Validating the Date of birth field in Android

Tags: android, validation, datepicker, android-sqlite, android-datepicker

In my application i have a date of birth field which i need to validate... The validate condition is that the user should not select the current date and if selected it show an error message...
The date is being selected from a `DatePickerDialog` in this way:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    tv_dob.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")

            .append(mYear - 1).append(" "));
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};


final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tv_applndate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
            .append(year));
```

How do i validate this date field?

Comment: what you have tried then ? add some logic to check such as `date < currDate`

Comment: You can also use `setMaxDate(long maxDate)` (API level 11)

Comment: Store today's date i.e. day, month and year in variable and compare to those varaible you are getting from date dialog picker after entering user.

Comment: [Refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15834544/2345913)

Answer (score 2):

Paste below function and replace your dialog id, button id,and edit text id simplest way for Date of birth date picker. you can use normal date picker if you want just remove vaidation for future date it wwill work as a normal date picker

```
    private void setDateTimeField() {

    et_dob.setOnClickListener(this);
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US); //dd/MM/yyyy

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dobDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            Date current = newDate.getTime();
             int diff1 =new Date().compareTo(current);

                if(diff1<0){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select a valid date",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    et_dob.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                }

        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
et_dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }

    });
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    if (et_dob.getText().toString() != null) {
        try {
            calendar.setTime(df.parse(et_dob.getText().toString()));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
    } else {
        mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    if (cal_currentTime.compareTo(calendar) > 0)
        updateDisplay();
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;

        String dateSetter = (new StringBuilder().append(mYear).append("-")
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append(""))
                .toString();
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (dateSetter != null) {
            try {
                cal.setTime(df.parse(dateSetter));
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
            month = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
        }

        if (cal_currentTime.compareTo(cal) > 0)
            updateDisplay();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Choose Proper date format",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private void updateDisplay() {
    dateOfBirth = (new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mYear).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mDay).append("")).toString();
    et_dob.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-").append(month).append("-")
            .append(mYear));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this validation in ondateset compareTo method returns 1 if greater and -1 if smaller

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(year, month, day);
        Date current = cal.getTime();

        int diff1 =new Date().compareTo(current);

        if(diff1>0){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Please select a valid date.",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to compare the selected date with the current date in the system inside your `OnDateSetListener`.

```
    Calendar selectedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    selectedCal.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
    Date selectedDate = selectedCal.getTime();
    Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    int diff1 = selectedDate.compareTo(currentDate);
    if(diff1>0){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please select a valid date",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
  // otherwise your date is valid
```